# .wait() "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i have been trying to stop my script from continuing to run while my modal alert box is being displayed. i'm pretty sure i need to use the .wait() to wait for the ok button to be clicked.

this is the code to display my dialogue and apply text to it.

```
function notify(heading,text){
   $("#errorHeading").empty();
   $( "#errorTxt").empty();
   var msg = $.mobile.changePage( "#confirm", { role: "dialog" } )+ $("#errorHeading").append(heading) + $( "#errorTxt" ).append("<p>"+text +"</p>" );
$("#confirmOK").wait('click');
}
```

this is the HTML dialogue itself

```
    <div data-role="dialog" id="confirm" data-title="Are you sure?">
    <div data-role="content">
        <h3 class="confirmHead" id="errorHeading">???</h3>
        <p class="confirmMessage" id="errorTxt">???</p>
        <a href="#" id="confirmOK" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-rel="back">OK</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i click the OK button to close the dialogue i get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function client.js:393
notify client.js:393
$.ajax.success client.js:254
c jquery-1.10.2.js:3048
p.fireWith jquery-1.10.2.js:3160
k jquery-1.10.2.js:8235
n.onload.n.onreadystatechange
```

if anybody could offer up a solution i would be grateful.

thanks in advance

EDIT

the reason i need the script to stop and wait for the click event is if i have a notification followed immediately by changing the page, the notification doesn't remain visible for more than a second.

e.g.

```
notify("", "you may now log in as: " + $("#R_email").val()); //pause need it to pause here because the next line forces the notification to dissapear
window.location.replace("#changeUser");
```

Comment: What is line 393 in `client.js`?

Comment: That is not a jQuery function that I'm aware of. When you say "stop my script from continuing to run," what are you referring to?

Comment: @Archer line 393 is $("#confirmOK").wait('click');

Comment: i edited the post to further explain my problem, i hope this clarifies what i am trying to do for @Mike

Comment: There is no JQuery function wait(). https://api.jquery.com/?s=wait

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `wait` is not a function in this context. Therefore the error is `undefined is not a function`. `$('confirmOK').wait` equals `undefined`, and you are calling it as a function.

There is no such thing as a `wait` or `sleep` in JavaScript. The closest thing would be `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of waiting for the button to be clicked, you may execute the remaining of the code (the code after the "wait()") as a call back function that is executed when "confirm" button is clicked.

Ex:

```
    var callback = function () {
        window.close();
    }

    $("#confirmOK").click(callback);

    //Show your modal dialog;
```